# How to fix Django Oscar application.urls, when changed to custom path (/store) breaks login redirect link from checkout

Tags: python, django, e-commerce, django-oscar

Changing `url(r'', include('application.urls'))` to `url(r'^store/', include('application.urls'))` causes login redirect url to fail from checkout from cart as anonymous user.

I have included `LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL = '/store/accounts/'` in `settings.py`.

This fixes the direct login redirect url.

However if an anonymous user tries to add product to cart, it is supposed to redirect to login page `/store/accounts/login/?next=/store/checkout/` but it redirects to `/accounts/login/?next=/store/checkout/`.

What is the workaround to fix this without breaking anything?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`LOGIN_URL = '/store/accounts/login/'`

Adding this line in settings.py fixed the problem.